# FTP and get row count from a file

Tags: bash, unix, ftp, mainframe

**FTP Server** -  xxx.xx.xxx.xxx (Mainframe)

**Unix**

```
$> ftp xxx.xx.xxx.xxx 
$> get filename
```

**Problem**

In the utility , we want to get **row count from a file**.

It can be done by :

- Get the file in UNIX path using ftp
- Apply `wc -l` on that file.

But we have few issues on the above technique:

- Space issue (File size > 100 GB).
- Resource and time consuming.

Any easy solution **to get row-count from a file using FTP**.

Comment: Just thinking outside the box here, do you have ssh-access?

Comment: Nope....Connecttion Refused...any other idea !!

Comment: really, wc -l (or similar) on the remote machine... ftp can't do that unless the remote server's administrators specifically added (and allowed) the "wc" binary into the ftp bin/ directory, and then you can use : `quote wc -l file` to execute it.

Comment: What's the purpose of the row count? If you want to check whether or not you want to download the file, the requirements are quite different from, say, checking whether the file has grown. What do you actually want to accomplish?

Comment: @triplee Count no. of lines in the file without downloading the file into my system...as downloading the files (> 50GB) will create space issue.

Comment: If the file has to be transferred but not stored locally, is that acceptable? You have still not revealed what the actual end goal is. Maybe a larger local disk would actually be the cheapest solution, but with so narrow a context, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Get whatever created the data to provide a count, use that. Could do lots of other things to ensure you have the correct file, correct date, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USS on the mainframe has the wc utility installed. Assuming you have to run your utility on a distributed system you could use FTP to submit a JCL job that used bpx batch to run the wc utility on the USS file you’re interested in. You could pipe the wc output to a file and then retrieve that file for use in your utility.

Comment: -1 This makes a load of unwarranted assumptions about the OP's environment, and is not on-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Since the Mainframe is z/OS and UNIX system services is included with the base z/OS system how am I making unwarranted assumptions about the environment? Mainframe’s generally have much higher levels of customizations then generic x86 servers. Unless you are the systems programmer for the asker you don’t know whether my assumptions about available programs are accurate.

Comment: Oh, it is on topic for Stack Overflow. This question reads like many others written by people who are accessing mainframe data but refuse or do not want to learn more about the versatile platform. Jared is perfectly in his right to answer as he did.

Comment: "Mainframe" does not equal z/OS (it could be a number of different architectures, including Unix) and the topic of Stack Overflow is programming.  Perhaps the question should be moved to ServerFault but as it stands, it could be perceived as a programming question.

Comment: This is the summary of the Tag Mainframe: "The mainframe tag refers to the class of "big iron" computers, primarily those from IBM. Currently this is limited to the System z hardware."

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

Create some script or program that periodically check the number of line and write it to a file, eg number_of_line.txt

Ftp the file number_of_line.txt and extract the information.